# How to get CMake to add files to MSVC's Solution tree?

Tags: visual-c++, cmake

Is there a way to get CMake to add files to MSVC's Solution Explorer tree as for example a "Solution item"? I have placed a bunch of CMake macros in a file called "helper_functions.cmake" and would like this file to appear in MSVC's Solution Explorer. This is so that team members can see that the file exists, (as per the CMakeLists.txt files that appear under their projects in the Solution Explorer tree).

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the file to the sources of the library or executable

```
PROJECT(FooBar)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(FooBar 
                main.cpp
                helper_functions.cmake # additional file
               )
```

Comment: This doesn't add them as solution items, though.  It adds them as items under the specified target.  Solution items are handy for files that aren't associated with any specific target but that you still reference from the IDE frequently.

Answer (score -1):

source_group("Helper Macros" FILES helper_functions.cmake) see more info at http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command:source_group

Comment: This only works to make the file appear inside the project tree, not the solution tree. Also it requires the file to be listed as a source too.

Comment: As Klaim describes, this does not answer the question

Comment: Well, for me it works. It does exactly what I need. I use source_group and I also add the files as source.