# Is it possible to add files to a CMake generated solution folder in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

This question is more or less a warmup of this question:

[how to get cmake to add files to msvcs solution tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4305337/how-to-get-cmake-to-add-files-to-msvcs-solution-tree)

It never got a valid answer so I want to repose it slightly different:

Is it possible to use the cmake solution folders that where introduced with cmake 2.8.3 to add files directly to the vs solution? I want to do the cmake equivalent of VS->Solution->Add->Existing Item. So my file will appear in a folder that belongs to the solution and not to a project.

I found examples how the solution folders can be used to group targets into folders with code like this:

```
set_property( GLOBAL PROPERTY USE_FOLDERS ON)
set_property(TARGET ${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTY FOLDER "Test")
```

So can I add a file instead of a target to the folder?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably not possible.

CMake organizes its assets into *projects* and *targets*. The project is what corresponds to Visual Studio's solution file while each target will generate a Visual Studio project inside the respective solution.

The problem is now that CMake does not allow to add files to CMake projects. In fact, a CMake project is little more than a collection of targets and offers almost no customization options. Hence the `USE_FOLDERS` option you mentioned can only be used to group VS projects inside a solution, but not single files.

The closest to what you ask would probably be to add a [custom target](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_target) that holds your files. However, this will still generate a VS project (which also contains a bunch of other stuff besides your files) inside the solution and not a plain folder.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I would vote you up but I am a man of low reputation. What is the common way to add global files like cmake macros to the project/solution then?

Comment: There is no 'best' way to do this. CMake itself tends to put all files related to a target into that target's VS project: For example, each VS project always contains the CMakeLists.txt that was used to create it, even if that leads to the same CMakeLists.txt appearing multiple times in the solution. So if you chose a similar approach that would at least be consistent. Depending on the nature of your files and your personal workflow a different form of organizing files might make more sense. For example, I personally never edit CMake files from within VS so I don't include them at all.

Comment: I used to do that too but I recently installed the cmake syntax highlighting plugin for VS and now I edit the files in VS. I guess I will use the "include the global files in all targets" approach with an extra folder in the target that contains the files.

Comment: Maybe relevant answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15989634/visual-studio-2010-project-file-filters/15990514#comment31651007_15990514

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, I think I know how to do it:

```
set(FILES_TO_ADD
    file1
    file2
    file3)

source_group("Group Name" FILES ${FILES_TO_ADD})
```

The `source_group` command creates the folder inside the Visual Studio project.

Comment: No I wanted to create a folder on the Visual Studio sollution level. As you said, your suggestion creates a folder under the Visual Studio project. I wanted to create a folder for files that do not really belong to any target, like files that contain CMake functions or global macros etc... In the VS GUI you can add items to the sollution and it will create a folder called "Soultion Items". That is what i wanted to achieve with CMake, but I failed

Comment: @Knitschi: Were you able to get this done?

Comment: @munsing No, I am still using the workaround from below where I add an extra custom target that does nothing and contains the global files.

Answer (score 0):

This answer just adds an example for the "custom target" solution that was proposed by ComicSansMS in the accepted answer. This is what I currently use to add my global files.

```
set( SOLUTION_FILES 
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt               # root CMakeLists file
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/macros.cmake           # cmake functions
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeInCodeDefinitions.h.in  # imported cmake variables
    # etc...
)

add_custom_target( GlobalFiles SOURCES ${SOLUTION_FILES})
```

Comment: Promising approach, but results in a target that is always out of date, so not harmless.

Comment: Have you had any problems with that? I am using this a lot to simply add all sorts of files to my visual studio solution just to make sure they are included in global searches. At least with the Visual Studio generator it seems not that there is anything done when building such a target. Maybe other build tools like ninja behave differently.

Comment: It does a no-op build instead of skipping the target. A small overhead, but it does result in extra "clutter" in the build log that wouldn't be necessary if this was supported more directly by cmake. It's subjective whether that's a problem, but I'd personally rather not have that. I agree that your proposal is a reasonable work-around, but not quite a solution (to me).